# Помогите перевести с align-valign на css

Tags: html, css

Ребята, мне надо перевести верстку текста с `align-valign` на `css`, пробовал что-то сделать, не получается одновременно выровнять по верху и по центру, вот текущий код:

```css
body {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
table,
td,
th,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
pre {
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
td {
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Labb2 d</title>

  <style type="text/css">
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <h3>Grundtabell</h3>
  <div>
    <table style="width:800px;">
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>F</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>G</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>I</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>J</td>
        <td>K</td>
        <td>L</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <h3>Asymetrisk tabell</h3>
  <div>
    <table style="width:800px;">
      <tr style="height:120px;">
        <td valign="top" align="center">A</td>
        <td valign="middle" align="center" colspan="2">B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height:200px;" rowspan="2">D</td>
        <td style="height:100px;">E</td>
        <td valign="bottom" align="right" rowspan="2">F</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height:100px;">H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height:60px;">
        <td valign="bottom" align="center" colspan="3">J</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <!-- W3C logos for valid HTML5 and CSS3 -->
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer">
        <img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_64.png" alt="Valid HTML5" height="50" width="50" style="border:0;" />
      </a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">
        <img style="border:0;width:88px;height:31px" src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss-blue" alt="Valid CSS!" />
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/az1mfa77/

Надо оставить такое же размещение букв в `td`, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить высоту ячейке или строке. У вас стоит паддинг одинаковый вверху и внизу, который центрирует текст по вертикали.

```
td{
  padding: 10px;  
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Или добавить разные паддинги вверху и внизу:

```
td{
  padding: 10px 10px 50px;      
  text-align: center;
}
```

[Демо](https://jsfiddle.net/az1mfa77/1/):

```css
body {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
table,
td,
th,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
pre {
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
td {
  padding: 10px 10px 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Labb2 d</title>

  <style type="text/css">
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <h3>Grundtabell</h3>
  <div>
    <table style="width:800px;">
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>F</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>G</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>I</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>J</td>
        <td>K</td>
        <td>L</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <h3>Asymetrisk tabell</h3>
  <div>
    <table style="width:800px;">
      <tr style="height:120px;">
        <td valign="top" align="center">A</td>
        <td valign="middle" align="center" colspan="2">B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height:200px;" rowspan="2">D</td>
        <td style="height:100px;">E</td>
        <td valign="bottom" align="right" rowspan="2">F</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height:100px;">H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height:60px;">
        <td valign="bottom" align="center" colspan="3">J</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <!-- W3C logos for valid HTML5 and CSS3 -->
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer">
        <img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_64.png" alt="Valid HTML5" height="50" width="50" style="border:0;" />
      </a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">
        <img style="border:0;width:88px;height:31px" src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss-blue" alt="Valid CSS!" />
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Просьба:**

При постановке вопроса, форматируйте свой код аккуратно, чтобы была возможность прочитать его с первого раза, не всматриваясь.

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне очень помогли!)